# R write EXIF data to JPEG file

Tags: r, exif

For R I found an opportunity to only read the EXIF data.

Is there any possibility in R to write EXIF data to JPEG file?

Comment: Probably best to use R to call an external exif tools program with command line parameters.

Comment: what OS do you use?

Comment: I use ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I've been toying with a wrapper for http://www.exiv2.org/. If you can add a list of tags you want to write (I know it needs to ultimately be generic to support all valid Exif tags) to the question, I may be able to whip something up quickly. It'll require that system library to be installed tho.

Comment: Keep a watch on https://github.com/hrbrmstr/exiv. I won't have many cycles for it this week but will be poking at it on occasion. The more complex types are going to be a pain, tho. So it might just be ascii, and basic numeric (perhaps date) in the short-term. it's ASCII for now and just add/modify. Delete'll be there eventually.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I hope you make that package available for us Windows users soon... :) looking to modify GPS coords in my exif data.

Comment: I have no real way to build third party binary libraries for Windows @Nova and am kinda terrified of all t he CRAN packages that download them from GitHub (https://github.com/rwinlib/) when they install things (it's a really insecure practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all who responded. As a result, I obtained the following solution.

Install [ExifTool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/),
I use Ubuntu comand:

**sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl**

Then in my R code, to add GPS coordinates to image I use:

```
exiftool_cmd <- paste("exiftool -GPSLongitudeRef=E -GPSLongitude=",latlon_exif[i,11]," -GPSLatitudeRef=N -GPSLatitude=",latlon_exif[i,10]," ","./nodejpg/",latlon_exif[i,4],".jpg",sep='')
system(exiftool_cmd)
```

Where *latlon_exif[i,11]* and *latlon_exif[i,10]* - coordinates, *latlon_exif[i,4]* - name of file.

To add data and time  to image I use:

```
exiftool_cmd <- paste("exiftool -alldates=",shQuote(date_exif[which(date_exif[,4]%in%latlon_exif[i,4]),8])," ","./nodejpg/",latlon_exif[i,4],".jpg",sep='')
system(exiftool_cmd)
```

Where *shQuote(date_exif[which(date_exif[,4]%in%latlon_exif[i,4]),8])* data and time in format: *'2017-11-16 22:33:17'*

Comment: You are assuming here that you are in the NE hemisphere, right?